# HWIOAuth + FOSUser password redirection

Tags: symfony, service

I used this [version](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697) to implement the 2 bundles. However, I want the user to set a password for his account so after successful authentification and user creation, he'll be refirected to a form where he'll enter that. Since `FOSUBUserProvider` is a service, I was thinking to make another service that will handle the password form. I injected the second service into the first one but I need `@templating` which I've set up as a parameter but I have no idea how to take it and I'm getting a warning that he's missing. How do I solve this?

```
#   /FOSUBUserProvider
$passwordSetter = Controller::get('register_social_password_picker');
```

I understand that it needs a second parameter(for `templating`), where do I take it from? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
class RegisterPassword
{

    protected $user;
    protected $templating;

    public function __construct($user, $templating)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }
...
}
```

services.yml

```
my_user_provider:
    class: AppBundle\Security\Core\FOSUBUserProvider
    arguments: [@fos_user.user_manager,{facebook: facebook_id, twitter: twitter_id, linkedin: linkedin_id}, "@register_password" ]

register_password:
    class:        AppBundle\Service\RegisterPassword
    arguments:    ["@templating" ]
```

LE: 
services.yml

```
register_password:
    class:        AppBundle\Service\RegisterPassword
    arguments:    [ setMailer, ["@templating"] ]


class RegisterPassword
{
    protected $user;
    protected $templating;

    public function __construct( )
    {

    }

    public function setPassword(User $user, $templating)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
...
}
```

Comment: I understand you registered this class as a service. Could you show your service definition?

Comment: sure, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the service constructor is expecting two arguments ($user and $templating) and you are passing only one (@templating). These parameters are passed when the service is built, so my guess is that you do not want $user to be a parameter for the constructor (at this point you do not know which user is going to use the service), so just pass the $templating parameter and you can add the user later on with a different call.

Since this seems to generate a circular reference problem, you may use one of three different strategies:

- Inject the full service container and get the templating service when you need it (not recommended)
- Use setter injection (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html)
  Since this calls the setter method after the service is built my guess is that the circular reference will be avoided (not 100% sure)
- If this does not work, create the setter method but do not call it at service construction point but rather call it later when you want to use the service

Comment: Ok, that was true. However, now I'm getting `Circular reference detected for service "security.authentication.manager", path: "security.firewall.map.context.secured_area -> security.authentication.manager -> my_user_provider -> register_password -> templating -> twig -> security.authorization_checker". `

Comment: No, the same error, the problem's still here. Probably something's wrong in the way the services are injected

Comment: Which of my suggestions did you try?

Comment: Can you show the code for the third option? That should work with no problems

Comment: Is the services.yml still as shown in your question? You should remove the @templating parameter for the register_password service as you will be passing it directly when you call set Password

Comment: yea, by removing it, it went one step further

Answer (score 0):

However, the approach I tried was a little off, the redirection after login can be easily set in security.yml>security>firewalls>firewall_name>default_target_path
Mine looks like:

```
default_target_path: /redirect
```